# Is there are way to read a windows storage space from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage

I have a windows storage space setup on my windows 10 instalation. The storage space includes only a single NTFS drive (sdb) and the drive is only used for storing media, windows is installed on a separate ssd (sda) and so is ubuntu (sdc).

Previously I had to disable quick startup on windows in order for ubuntu to be able to read the files in my windows drive (sda). In this case ubuntu doesn't even detect my media drive.

Is there any way in which I can read and write from my media drive from ubuntu gnome or linux in general?

**Update:**

I can see the drive by using `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   350M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   111G  0 part /media/myusername/F04C0DC34C0D8616
└─sda3   8:3    0   450M  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0   2,7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0   2,7T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   0 214,7G  0 part /
└─sdc5   8:37   0   8,9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

I'm trying to read `sdb/sdb2`.

When I use `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/myusername/mediadrive`

I get:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

When I execute `sudo parted -l` the output is:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  368MB  367MB  primary  ntfs         boot
 2      368MB   120GB  119GB  primary  ntfs
 3      120GB   120GB  472MB  primary  ntfs         diag


Model: ATA ST3000DM001-1CH1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17,4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   3001GB  3000GB               Grupo de almacenamiento


Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 2      1049kB  231GB  231GB   primary   ext4            boot
 1      231GB   240GB  9499MB  extended
 5      231GB   240GB  9499MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: How is it formatted? NFTS / FAT? Is it directly connected?

Comment: @Tim nfts. It's an internal drive and its directly connected.

Comment: @MrD I add screen-shot. See in below.

Comment: @MrD Give me answer this command : echo $USER

Comment: @k-five I'd rather not, the computer isn't mine. You can assume its `myusername` tho

Comment: @MrD Did you see that photo I put below.

Comment: @k-five Yes, I already tried that, output error is in the updated answer

Comment: @MrD ___ Please give me the result of      ->     sudo parted -l

Comment: @k-five done, included in the answer

Comment: @MrD What is the "sdb" format ?  I mean file system

Comment: @k-five ntfs I'm pretty sure tho that may not be the case since I don't know how windows storage spaces work exactly

Comment: @MrD I do not know because I do not see any File System in your sudo parted -l. Maybe your hard drive is so large and you have to divide it to 3 part ( each part = 1 T ).

Comment: @MrD you can ask in chat room. Because of I have to go . very sorry. https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com

Answer (score 4):

Storage Spaces are based on a new proprietary file system from Microsoft called [ReFS (resilient file system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS)

At the time of writing, there is no Open Source software that allows to mount this kind of file system, the only option right now is to use proprietary software:

[ReFS for Linux by Paragon Software](https://www.paragon-software.com/business/refs-linux/)

Note: I am not affiliated with Paragon Software in any way, I am just stating the facts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes :

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/myusername/mount-point
```

## OR

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/$USER/mount-point
```

First use this command to show your hard `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   100G  0 part /media/shu/temp
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 190.8G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0 638.9G  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part
├─sdb2   8:18   0 931.5G  0 part
└─sdb3   8:19   0 931.5G  0 part /media/shu/movie
```

then go to /media/$USER

Notice : $USER = your username. For Example my username name is shu

and create one mount point

Such as cd /media/shu

then`sudo mkdir windrive`

then if you have `ntfs` use `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/$USER/anyname`

but if you have `fat32` use `sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda4 /media/$USER/fat32 -o    uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022`

---

Sample : I want to mount `sdb3`

[image]

> Because I already mounted `sdb3` give me an error, but for you work.
>
> 1. lsblk
> 2. cd /media/shu # your username
> 3. sudo mkdir mount-point
> 4. sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /media/shu/mount-point

Comment: what's /dev/ in the mount command? I'm getting mount: special device /dev/sdb2/ does not exist (a path prefix is not a directory)

Comment: When I use lsblk I can see that I want to mount (sdb/sdb2).
If I replace dev for sdb I get mount: special device /sdb/sdb2/ does not exist instead.

Comment: @MrD /dev/ is a path to mount the partition.  And /media/shu/mount-point is a path to load your files.

Comment: @MrD Did you format it ? I mean sdb2 that is 2.7T !!!

Comment: Just a small thing, but `/media` is meant for detachable storage, like USB sticks, SD cards, and the like. `/mnt` is meant for permanently attached storage, like internal HDD's, SSD's, etc... It won't make any difference which you use, and is purely organisational, but it's considered good practice to keep things separated like that, and it's a good habit to get in to. Who knows, one day you might work looking after a server farm, and struggle to get out of the bad habits you adopted years ago.

Comment: @Jack_Hu, Hi && thanks for fixing typos && the explanation

Answer (score 2):

You probably cannot read the Windows Storage Space using any current tools in Linux. It's not a matter of detecting and mounting it, it's a matter of reading Microsoft's proprietary virtual file system. It is a similar problem as if you had a LVM2 volume which you are trying to open from Windows, you can see it's there, but reading it is another matter. Also, because you don't know how it works, I highly recommend not mounting it or otherwise poking it; especially if this isn't your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/winfiles
```

not "mount /sdb/sdb2" and not "mount /dev/sdb2/"(sdb2 is treated as a file not a directory).

If this gives you an error, sdb2 doesn't exist or anything, type

```
cd /dev
ls
```

and check if a file named sdb2 is in the folder "/dev"

Comment: There is a file `sdb2` in the `/dev` folder

Comment: Then try the command "sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/winfiles" and see if it works.

Comment: I did, output is in the updated answer